git rev-list working locally but failing in pipeline
I have a stage in my pipeline like below:
stage("Pre Flight Checks") {
            steps {
                echo 'using the message count externally'
                script {
                    // Execute the shell command and assign the result to an environment variable
                    def messageCount = sh(script: "git rev-list origin/${env.DEV_BRANCH_NAME}..origin/${env.BRANCH_NAME} --oneline | wc -l", returnStdout: true).trim()
                    env.message_count = messageCount
                }
                echo "message_count: ${env.message_count}"
                preFlightChecks()
            }
        }

I have defined few validations in my dsl lib function preFlightChecks() to run some checks.
Here is the problem i am getting:
13:35:52  + git rev-list origin/develop..origin/release_10122024_1 --oneline
13:35:52  fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/develop..origin/release_10122024_1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
13:35:52  Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
13:35:52  'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
13:35:52  + wc -l

I am trying to identify the number of commit differences between the 2 branches and parse the logic based on that value.
while the same command works fine when i am running locally.
works intermittently over the CI.
How to understand this behaviour? i am clueless !! dear experts please provide your inputs.

Let me guess: working on a shallow clone?

No @eftshift0. i am using advanced clone behaviour only for fetch tags.No shallow clone.

OK.... let's play safe... can you run this in the pipeline before doing that failing command? git rev-parse origin/develop and git rev-parse origin/release_10122024_1? If you get 2 IDs out of that (which would be quite a shocker), let us know.

And... you are fetching before trying to run that, right?

yes @eftshift0 . i am fetching it before for sure :).
I got 2 different IDs out of that, which is expected.
but now a followup step is throwing error.
15:08:52  + git rev-parse HEAD~1
15:08:52  fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
15:08:52  Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
15:08:52  'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
15:08:52  HEAD~1
```**
This happened on the same run. This is the main concerning thing. The git commands are behaving so flaky way.

I would definitely check my assumptions about what you are working with. That kind of message is what I would expect to see on a shallow clone.... or are you at that point at a very root commit?
